# Make Swift Class to make Http Requests

Tags: ios, swift, http

I made this class below to help make http requests from anywhere in my application, however when i call the class it does not make the request as expected. I see i can print from the function so i know it is making it that far at least. What else do i need to make this request?? the api parameter is being passed correctly as well.

in viewController:

```
let url = "post/test"
MakeHttpRequest.sharedInstance.postRequest(api: url)
```

in class:

```
import Foundation

final class MakeHttpRequest {
    static let sharedInstance = MakeHttpRequest()
    var api_token = "token_here"
    var url_base = "https://test.frb.io/"
    func postRequest (api : String) {
        let parameters = ["email": "testing123@gmail.com"]
        guard let destination = URL(string: url_base + api) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: destination)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //            request.setValue("clientIDhere", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
            else { return }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if (json["response"]) != nil {

                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        print(url_base + api)
    }
    private init() {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I changed it.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the request and resume into 2 separate calls? Something like `let task = session.dataTask(...)   task.resume`. I have seen instances where the chaining of some swift object does not work as intended.

Comment: Also try adding an else to your `if let data = data` you might be erring out and not know it.

Comment: cool thanks you helped alot! how would i pass the let parameters with the email to the function? the api is a string so what the paramater would be array?

Comment: You can just add an optional parameters dictionary to the func and check if it is not nil and if so add the body request. Something like `if let parameters = parameters { guard ... request.httpBody = ` Let me know if you want me to type the full answer.

Comment: yes full answer please so i can vote it

Comment: There you go glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things to check. Sometimes swift function chaining doesn't work properly. So try splitting the session.dataTask and resume into two statements. And second try adding error handling to the response. You may be getting an error without knowing it. See code sample below.

```
import Foundation

final class MakeHttpRequest {
    static let sharedInstance = MakeHttpRequest()
    var api_token = "token_here"
    var url_base = "https://test.frb.io/"
    func postRequest (api: String, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil) {
        guard let destination = URL(string: url_base + api) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: destination)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //            request.setValue("clientIDhere", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        if let parameters = parameters {
            guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return
            }
            request.httpBody = httpBody
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if (json["response"]) != nil {
                        print("1234")
                    } else {
                        print("ABCD")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            } else {
                print(error ?? "")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        print(url_base + api)
    }

    private init() {
    }
}

let url = "post/test"
MakeHttpRequest.sharedInstance.postRequest(api: url)
```